# Navigation Icon no longer firing SlidingMenu after implementing ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

When first experimenting with the SlidingMenu library by jfeinstein10, in the example project, clicking the icon button in the action bar would cause the sliding menu to open and then close when clicked again.  After implementing ActionBarSherlock and getting it to run (not throwing any errors), the icon no longer causes the menu to appear.  So far I have changed the SlidingMenu library to extend SherlockActivity instead of extending android Activity as suggested in the SlidingMenu read me. I have also changed the following lines in BaseActivity:

Original:

```
// customize the ActionBar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Changed to:

```
// customize the ActionBar
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

It seems as if the button press is being registered in LogCat, but it's not doing anything.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and just wanted to see if anyone has experienced this issue or is familiar enough with both/either libraries to quickly help pinpoint where I'm going wrong or what I forgot to do.

Thanks!

Comment: It should also be noted that the menu is still able to be accessed by dragging from the edge of the screen (or, depending on the settings, from anywhere on the screen) so the libraries seem to be working together, just not to their full potential.

Comment: do you tried it on android <= 2.3.x, dos the actionbar appear ?

Comment: @JafarKhQ, yep I just tested on a phone running 2.2.2.  So actionbarShelock is working and SlidingMenu is working, I just don't know how to make the home button cause the menu to toggle. I think I'm on to something, just haven't had much time to work on it it due to school. Hopefully I can figure it out this weekend.

Comment: can you post onOptionsItemSelected() code, and your imports OR the activity class with the imports

Comment: `import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;`

Comment: `@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case android.R.id.home:
   Toast.makeText(this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   toggle();
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. I'm not sure of the best way to post the code.

Comment: On a side note, I noticed that Toast.* never gets called, so I'm guessing it has something to do with android.R.id.home not actually being related to the Home icon when using ABS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your problem

```
import android.view.MenuItem
```

you must use Shearlock Menu not android Menu.

remove android MenuItem import and use Shearlock one`s

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem as well, and was already importing the actionbarsherlock menu and menuitem libraries.

What did the trick for me was adding the following to the onOptionsItemSelected function so the relevant toggle function was called when the home button action was triggered...

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getSlidingMenu().toggle();
            return true;

        ...     
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```